# How to generate date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I want to generate list of dates between `20160711` to `20190921`. I don't want to miss a date. How to do that in Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add what you have tried by far and ask for the specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1546]: start_dt = '20160711'

In [1547]: end_dt = '20190921'


In [1549]: start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y%m%d')

In [1550]: end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_dt, '%Y%m%d')

In [1551]: step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

In [1552]: date_list = []

In [1553]: while start <= end:
      ...:     date_list.append(start.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
      ...:     start += step
      ...:
```

`date_list` is a list of dates from the `start` to `end`.

```
In [1554]: date_list
Out[1554]: 
 ['2016-07-11',
 '2016-07-12',
 '2016-07-13',
 '2016-07-14',
 '2016-07-15',
 '2016-07-16',
 '2016-07-17',
 '2016-07-18',
......
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I want next 52 weeks to be generated, so I will not be knowing exact start and end data, how can I do that